# Why am I getting an white screen when I activate the developer mode with my custom module installed?

Tags: javascript, odoo, openerp-7, qweb

I'm developing a simple picture gallery for the OpenERP v7 because I need to write mail templates with hosted images in the server.

I'm programming this functionality modifying the module web_ckeditor4.

The main problem I have is when I enable the **developer mode** the screen becomes white and I get a JavaScript error (the qweb2.js file throws ):

```
Uncaught Error: QWeb2: This page contains the following errors:error on line 1 at column 52: Space required after the Public Identifier
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

The snippet of the qweb2.js file with the exception that it throws

```
var QWeb2 = {
    expressions_cache: {},
    RESERVED_WORDS: 'true,false,NaN,null,undefined,debugger,console,window,in,instanceof,new,function,return,this,typeof,eval,void,Math,RegExp,Array,Object,Date'.split(','),
    ACTIONS_PRECEDENCE: 'foreach,if,call,set,esc,escf,raw,rawf,js,debug,log'.split(','),
    WORD_REPLACEMENT: {
        'and': '&&',
        'or': '||',
        'gt': '>',
        'gte': '>=',
        'lt': '<',
        'lte': '<='
    },
    tools: {
        exception: function(message, context) {
            context = context || {};
            var prefix = 'QWeb2';
            if (context.template) {
                prefix += " - template['" + context.template + "']";
            }
            throw new Error(prefix + ": " + message);
        },
```

I checked my JavaScript file and the template file of the view that I use and it seems the syntax is OK.

If anyone has any idea of what is happening I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I migrated the module to Odoo v8 and it seems everything works fine now. I don't know the reason why this is not working in OpenERP v7, but I don't care anymore

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone else, I received this error because I had a space as the first character in my qweb xml file.